# How to change the face of the text in the minibuffer when running in terminal mode?

Tags: terminal, colors, fonts, emacs, minibuffer

When pressing `M-x` in Emacs, the focus switches to the minibuffer. When running Emacs in terminal mode, I have found that this text is really difficult to read as it is dark blue and difficult to distinguish from the dark grey color of my terminal. How can I change the font color of the text I type into the minibuffer?

I want to do this from my `~/.emacs`, so that it happens every time I start Emacs in non-windowed mode.

I'm using Red Hat and the GNOME Terminal, if that makes any difference.

Comment: `M-x customize-face minibuffer-prompt` might be relevant. But it doesn't apply to the text you type; it applies only to the prompt for that text. (And I don't know whether it's used in terminal mode.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(minibuffer-prompt ((t (:foreground "orange")))))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?